# How to handle XML with unclosed tags?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session xmlns="http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0" name="test" start="2014-04-04T15:54:09.728Z">
  <upload>
    <filename value="D:\ftp\test1.TXT" />
    <destination value="/in/test1.TXT" />
    <result success="true" />
  </upload>
  <touch>
    <filename value="/in/test1.TXT" />
    <modification value="2014-03-27T12:45:20.000Z" />
    <result success="true" />
  <upload>
    <filename value="D:\ftp\test2.TXT" />
    <destination value="/in/test2.TXT" />
    <result success="true" />
  </upload>
  <touch>
    <filename value="/in/test2.TXT" />
    <modification value="2014-03-27T12:45:20.000Z" />
    <result success="false" />
  </touch>
</session>
```

I'd like to browse all filename elements where result success="true" for both nodes touch and upload .

I wrote the following code

```
 var upload = from el in root.Elements("upload") select el;
  var touch = from el in root.Elements("touch") select el;

  // use zip to join the two lists together based on ordering to a new object
  // this WON'T work if the lists are different lengths!
  var filename = upload.Zip(touch,(u,t) => new { upload = u, touch = t })
        .Where(item => item.upload.Descendants("result").First().Attribute("success").Value  == "true" 
                   &&  item.touch.Descendants("result").First().Attribute("success").Value  == "true")
        .Select(item => item.upload.Descendants("filename").First().Attribute("value").Value);
```

It works fine but my problems that sometimes I read xml with uclosed tags :
For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <session xmlns="http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0" name="test" start="2014-04-04T15:54:09.728Z">
      <upload>
        <filename value="D:\ftp\test1.TXT" />
        <destination value="/in/test1.TXT" />
        <result success="true" />
      </upload>
      <touch>
        <filename value="/in/test1.TXT" />
        <modification value="2014-03-27T12:45:20.000Z" />
        <result success="true" />
      <upload>
        <filename value="D:\ftp\test2.TXT" />
        <destination value="/in/test2.TXT" />
        <result success="true" />
```

In this case the code above will not work , How can I change it in order to read an xml file with unclosed tags ?

Many thanks in advance , any help would be the most appreciated !

Comment: XML with unclosed/missing tags is *not* XML; it is some text that happens to resemble XML. The best solution is to get [valid] XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as the collection wouldn't be valid unless the xml is valid. Consider validating the xml prior to running this code against it.